# JEE: How to intercept a @PostCostruct method?

Tags: interceptor, postconstruct, java-ee-8, wildfly-15, predestroy

I have a bean having:

- `void initialize()` method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.
- `void release()` method annotated with `@PreDestroy`.
- Some other methods.
- In addition that bean has a `@Interceptors` annotation defining some interceptors.

One of those interceptors has methods annotated with

- `@AroundConstruct`
- `@AroundInvoke`
- `@AroundTimeout`
- `@PostConstruct`
- `@PreDestroy`

In each of those methods I put some logging, so I can see which and when the interceptor methods are called. And the call order looks like this:

- Interceptor's `@AroundConstruct` method is entered.
  InvocationContext: Target is `null`, method is `null`, constructor is set.
- Beans constructor is called.
- The call exists through Interceptor's `@AroundConstruct` method.
  InvocationContext: Target is the bean instance, method is `null`, constructor is set.
- Interceptor's `@PostConstruct` method is called, calls proceed() and returns.
  InvocationContext: Target is the bean instance, method is `null`, constructor is set.
- After the previous call returned completely the bean's `@PostConstruct` method is called.

I was very surprised realizing that the `@PostConstruct` is not called during the bean's `@PostConstruct` method call, but between the construction of the bean and calling the bean's `@PostConstruct` method. Also the call of the bean's `@PostConstruct` method is not intercepted at all, not by the interceptor's `@PostConstruct` method nor bi its `@AroundInvoke` method.

Is there any mistake on my side / my programs side?

Is there any way to intercept the bean's `@PostConstruct` method (same goes for the `@PreDestroy` method)?

I need to prepare the context(s) and fill them with some content. In addition it would be also nice for other method deep down the call stack later to know that the call was triggered by the container through one of those two methods.

Answer (score 1):

As I couldn't find any answer on that in the Internet, I went through some debugging and found out the following (used WildFly 15.0.1.Final):

When a bean is instantiated:

- Entering interceptor's `@AroundConstruct` (InvocationContext: Constructor set)
- Executing bean's constructor
- Leaving interceptor's `@AroundConstruct` (InvocationContext: Constructur and target set)
- Entering interceptor's `@PostConstruct` (InvocationContext: Constructur and target set)
- Executing bean's `@PostConstruct`
- Leaving interceptor's `@PostConstruct` (InvocationContext: Constructur and target set)

This means that you don't know which method is called, you only know that the `@PostConstruct` method of the bean is called. I guess that's because the `@PostConstruct` method of the bean is executed as some kind of interceptor, but that is only an assumption on my side.

When you execute a bean's method:

- Entering interceptor's `@AroundInvoke` (InvocationContext: Method and target set)
- Executing bean's method
- Leaving interceptor's `@AroundInvoke` (InvocationContext: Method and target set)

When a bean is destroyed:

- Entering interceptor's `@PreDestroy` (InvocationContext: Target set)
- Executing bean's `@PreDestroy`
- Leaving interceptor's `@PreDestroy` (InvocationContext: Target set)

I hope that this will be also helpful to others.